# javascript function with document.querySelectorAll plus filter() can't work properly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get rid of those `<tr>` with `<span class="verfied-badge">` inside it using javascript. (please note that I am hoping for a solution that is javascript only, no jquery)

The HTML structure is like this:

```
<tr class="project-description">
  <td colspan="6">
    <div class="project-desc-inner">
      <div class="project-synopsis">
        <p class="trunk8">This is an entry</p>
      </div>
      <div class="project-verification">
        <span class="verfied-badge"> <~~~~~~~~~~ THIS SPAN
            <span class="currency-symbol">$</span>
            <span class="icon-tick"></span>
            Verified
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="project-actions">
        <a href="#">
            <button class="btn">LOL</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And this is as far as I can come up to:

```
function showAlert()
{
  document.querySelectorAll("tr.project-description").filter(document.getElementsByClassName("verfied-badge")).remove();
  alert("Unwanted removed.");
}
```

What I hope it does is, select all `tr.project-description` then from those get all with have `span.verfied-badge` and if it does have it, delete the entire `tr`

but as it seems, I keep failing :(

Hope somebody can help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to find the `span` items, then remove their great-great-grandparents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all the `tr` elements you care about, then see if they containing a matched `verified-badge` span. If they do, <s>burninate</s> remove them.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var projectDescriptions = document.querySelectorAll('tr.project-description'),
        projectDescriptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(projectDescriptions); 
    projectDescriptions.forEach(function(el) { 
        if (el.querySelector('span.verfied-badge')) { 
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    });
});
```

I called `Array.prototype.slice` on the `NodeList` returned from `querySelectorAll` because `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array but a `NodeList`, which is one of JavaScript's irritating (but easy to workaround) "Array-like objects".

Comment: it seems to be removing the `<span>`? not the `<tr>`

Comment: @TheWolf Not sure, on my browser (Firefox 35.0.1) I am left with `<table>
<tbody>

</tbody></table>` after running it.

Comment: you're right, its weird maybe because i'm using tampermonkey from Chrome. Thanks!